# How can I draw a cross in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The aim is to write function `drawACross` which returns a cross shape with `'x'` characters on a square grid of size and height of our sole input `n`. All non-`'x'` characters in the grid should be filled with a space character (`" "`).
The arms of the cross must only intersect through one central `'x'` character, and start in the corner of the grid, so for even values of `n`, return `"Centered cross not possible!"`

If `n < 3`, function should return `"Not possible to draw cross for grids less than 3x3!"`
This is my code, but in the result the cross is not centered:

```js
function drawACross(n) {
  if (n % 2 === 0) {
    console.log("Centered cross not possible!")
  } else if (n < 3) {
    console.log("Not possible to draw cross for grids less than 3x3!")
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      let arr = new Array(n)
      let y = arr.fill("", 0, arr.length)
      y.splice(arr.length - (i + 1), 1, "x")
      y.splice(i, 1, "x")
      console.log(y.join(" "))
    }
  }
}

drawACross(5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting with empty strings and joining with a space, start with spaces and join with an empty string.

```js
function drawACross(n) {
  if (n % 2 === 0) {
    console.log("Centered cross not possible!")
  } else if (n < 3) {
    console.log("Not possible to draw cross for grids less than 3x3!")
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      let arr = new Array(n)
      let y = arr.fill(" ", 0, arr.length)
      y.splice(arr.length - (i + 1), 1, "x")
      y.splice(i, 1, "x")
      console.log(y.join(""))
    }
  }
}

drawACross(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier (though a little less efficient) to work with a string that you compose character by character, observing the fact that that for a diagonal cross, the "marked" characters are those whose X coordinate is equal to the Y coordinate (and mirror the same).

```js
function drawACross(n) {
  if (n % 2 === 0) {
    console.log("Centered cross not possible!");
    return;
  }
  if (n < 3) {
    console.log("Not possible to draw cross for grids less than 3x3!");
    return;
  }
  for (let y = 0; y < n; y++) {
    let line = "";
    for (let x = 0; x < n; x++) {
      line += x == y || x == n - 1 - y ? "x" : " ";
    }
    console.log(line);
  }
}

drawACross(5);
```

Comment: Has advantage of being intuitive